# Authlogic - no implicit conversion of nil into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I'm updating an old Rails (Ruby v 2.5.6 & Rails v 4.2.10) app and I've hit a weird error where when a user attempts to log in, if the password is **incorrect** I get

> no implicit conversion of nil into Integer

on the line with

> if @user_session.save

All the code is stock from authlogic so I can't understand why it's occurring

```
class UserSessionsController < BaseGUIController
  include CurrentCart

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params)
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome back!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_session_params
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:email, :password, :remember_me)
  end
end
```

It should return @user_session as not saved and redirect the user back to the login for to try again. If the password is correct there is no issue.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste how your params are coming through to the controller and your UserSession model please

Comment: `if @user_session.try(:save)` should resolve the issue.

Comment: Show your UserSession model

Comment: First of all, you told from which version of Rails you're upgrading, but not to which version. Are you upgrading to Rails 5 or 6?

Comment: Just a hunch, but could be that you have a column for 'incorrect logins' or similar and it's trying to add 1 to this column and unable to do so because it is nil (rather than 0). Try doing an update all on this column to set to 0 where it is nil